# How to get iostat of a single process

Tags: iostat

How can I get iostats io throughput of just a process to try know if this process starts burning my HDD.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming a recent version of Linux, I'd look at the [iotop utility](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/).

You don't mention your distribution of Linux, but the tool is available for most in the default package repositories.

Comment: iotop does not show iops though, like iostat does, which is increasingly becoming a critical metric to track since that's a key throttle point for cloud vendors

Comment: @JacobDavis-Hansson I'm not even sure "The Cloud" was a major focus at the time I wrote this answer (8 years ago).

Comment: Oh my, I didn't realize how old this answer was. Fair!

Answer (score 2):

Some useful tools:

- iotop
- htop (as instructed by B14D3)
- btrace

... and if you ever need to see per-process network usage, try `nethogs`.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the I/O data from /proc/[pid]/io file (or simply /proc/self/io for the current process). I/O performed in subprocesses is inherited as those terminate, so reading the line "write_bytes" before and after your task should give a reasonable estimate. However, this doesn't take different devices into account.

Answer (score 1):

Htop  can display io stats per process. You have to only setup to display propper colums by pressing f2 and add io_rate io_write_reate and io_read_rate from menu Setup>Columns

You can use iotop.